# markdown bug in URLs inside italic (with underscore)

Tags: bug, markdown

Markdown issues:

```
_http://example.com_
```

gives

*http://example.com*

(italic but no hyperlink) and:

```
_anything http://example.com_
```

gives:

*anything [http://example.com](http://example.com_)*

Hyperlink but with a trailing `_` in the target URL and not in the link name (`<em>anything <a href="http://example.com_">http://example.com</a></em>`).

Also applies to `__http://example.com__`, but not `*http://example.com*` nor `**http://example.com**`.

Comment: Seems to be [quite a bit of disagreement](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?text=_http://example.com_%0A%0A_anything+http://example.com_) as to how that should render, but certainly the malformed URL is wrong at least